# Java Dozer - Element A to List<B>

Tags: java, dozer

I need to map two very similar complex objects.

For instance, I want to map class A and B which are (let's say) houses.
Class A is designed with one door only. (which is a class of its own, with its fields)
Class B is designed with a list of doors. (which is a mirror-like of the other door class)

There will always be only one door in the house, but I don't want to change Class A & B.

'til Today, I just can't map it with Dozer.
I tried things like:

```
<a>door</a>
<b>doors[0]</b>
<b-hint>path.to.doorB</b-hint>
```

Each time I get something like "no write method for B".

I can call the dozer conversion in java at the door level, but well it's such a pain in the.. And well the idea of using Dozer was so I could simplify the conversion process.

(Moreover I do have a lot of cases like this one)

Help would be greatly appreciated, with all of my gratitude given to whoever helps me on this one :).

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What if you add a method `setDoor(door)` in B that call `setDoors(Collections.singletonList(door))` ?

Comment: Hi Raphaël, A & B are auto-generated classes using XML Schemas. I don't want to modify them.

Comment: can't you use custom converter for this job

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify your auto-generated classes with adding setter as @Raphael says, you always can write a factory method to map two very similar complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

this functionality is already implemented by dozer what you have to do is to specify in the field mapping that you are going to map an element of the array field of class A to field in class B and it is done like this:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>A</class-a>
    <class-b>B</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>valueString[0]</a>
        <b>valueInteger</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```